# The query is always of type unknown when created with @graphql-codegen

Tags: typescript, graphql, graphql-codegen

I have a this graphql query:

```js
import { graphql } from '../__generated__/gql';

// typeof IndexPageQuery is unknown
const IndexPageQuery = graphql(`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    user {
      ...UserInputFragment
    }
  }
  ${UserInputFragment}
`);
```

And when i run this code:

```js
const { data } = await apolloClient.query(IndexPageQuery);
```

TS throw error:

```
Argument of type 'unknown' is not assignable to parameter of type 'QueryOptions<OperationVariables, any>'.ts(2345)
```

Why `IndexPageQuery` always has type `unknown`? Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm Charly, from The Guild, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

The `preset: 'client'` does not require to include fragments documents in the GraphQL operation definition (it does it for you automatically).

To fix your issue, please replace your `IndexPageQuery` with the following:

```
const IndexPageQuery = graphql(`
  query IndexPageQuery {
    user {
      ...UserInputFragment
    }
  }
`);
```

Comment: I have the exact same problem, but leaving out the inclusion does not fully solve it for me. I then get the error `UnknownFragment: "UserInputFragment"` from useQuery(). 

If I do not refer to the fragment by including the variable anymore, where/how do I properly define the fragment so that it is definitely considered and auto-included by the GraphQL Code Generator?

Comment: Ok I could solve it now by also including *.graphql files in the `documents: []` filter in my `CodegenConfig` and then just created a .graphql file where I define my fragments. (The rest of my schema I fetch from an GQL Endpoint where I do not want the fragments to be included)