# GraphQL Codegen duplicates RegisterDocument with typescript-urql

Tags: graphql-codegen

The codegen.ts config below results in duplicating the `RegisterDocument` entries.

codegen.ts:

```
const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  documents: "src/graphql/**/*.graphql",
  generates: {
    "src/generated/graphql": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: [
        "typescript-urql"
      ],
      config: {
        documentVariableSuffix: 'test2'
      }
    }
  }
};
```

the output:

```
export const RegisterDocument = {"kind":"Document", ...}

export const RegisterDocument = gql`
    mutation Register($username: String!, $password: String!) {
  register(options: {username: $username, password: $password}) {
    errors {
      field
      message
    }
    user {
      id
      username
      createdAt
    }
  }
}
    `;

export function useRegisterMutation() {
  return Urql.useMutation<RegisterMutation, RegisterMutationVariables>(RegisterDocument);
};
```

Seemingly either the `documentVariableSuffix` param didn't affect the output const naming or it was a wrong param. The use of the typescript-operations or/and typescript packages only led to more duplicates.

What is the way to have typescript-urql register the mutation differently?

UP. The `register` mutation I need typings for:

```
const registerMutationDocument = graphql(`
  mutation Register($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(options: { username: $username, password: $password }) {
      errors {
        field
        message
      }
      user {
        id
        username
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a few attempts with various code pieces it seems I've got it to work. Thank you mr. Poly for the hints.

Here's the take.
First, the present iteration of `graphql-codegen` watches for *.ts/*.tsx `documents` not *.graphql ones. Second the only plugins needed are the ones listed in the docs.

```
const config: CodegenConfig = {
  overwrite: true,
  schema: "http://localhost:4000/graphql",
  documents: "src/graphql/mutations/*.ts",
  generates: {
    "src/generated/graphql/": {
      preset: "client",
      plugins: []
    }
  }
};
```

Third the way to put the mutations etc. to a dedicated folder that I used was to create one at src/graphql/mutations. The register.ts holding the mutation had the following code:

```
import { graphql } from '../../generated/graphql';

export const registerMutationDocument = graphql(`
  mutation Register($username: String!, $password: String!) {
    register(options: { username: $username, password: $password }) {
      errors {
        field
        message
      }
      user {
        id
        username
        createdAt
      }
    }
  }
`);
```

The only problem for me was if I tried to add a field to it that didn't exist on the model the editor froze.
The usage within the component:

```
import { registerMutationDocument } from '../graphql/mutations/register';
...
const [, register] = useMutation(registerMutationDocument);
```

Comment: its seems import register.ts should be import { graphql } from '../../generated/gql';  e.g. change graphql to gql

Answer (score 14):

I'm Charly, from The Guild, working on GraphQL Code Generator.

The `preset: "client"` is not meant to be used in combination with other plugins.
You must use either the `client-preset` or `typescript-urql-plugin` which provides 2 different ways to get typed GraphQL Operations.

The `typescript-urql-plugin` generates React hooks while, the `client-preset` generated typed GraphQL documents that can be used with URQL's native `useQuery()` and `useMutation()`.

We now recommend using the `client-preset` that provides a better developer experience and smaller generated code for the same result.

You will find a guide to setup the `client-preset` with URQL here: https://the-guild.dev/graphql/codegen/docs/guides/react-vue

Comment: Did you by `typescript-urql-plugin` refer to `typescript-urql`? If so `typescript-urql` used with neither `preset: "client"` or `preset: "client-preset"` resulted in `Plugin "typescript-urql" validation failed`.

Comment: A full `useMutation` example would be of use to me if available.

Comment: Sure, please find a complete working URQL example of a mutation definition with the `client-preset` here: https://github.com/charlypoly/codegen-repros/blob/master/urql-client-preset-mutation/src/App.tsx#L6-L28

Comment: How do I type the `graphql` method output to Urlq'l `useMutation` since the former returns `unknown` and the latter accepts a `'string | DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode'`?

Comment: @ElAnonimo could you share the query you are trying to get typing from?
Please not that your query should not contains any inline fragment document, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74068078/the-query-is-always-of-type-unknown-when-created-with-graphql-codegen/74094939#74094939

Comment: It is the same one in the original post with `RegisterDocument` only replace `gql` with `graphql`, see the updated post.

Comment: Could you provide a use example of the `typescript-urql` too?

Comment: > How do I type the graphql method output to Urlq'l useMutation since the former returns unknown and the latter accepts a 'string | DocumentNode | TypedDocumentNode'? 



Did you installed `graphql` as a dev dependency and run `graphql-codegen` in watch mode?

Comment: You will find examples for URQL plugin usage in previous versions of our docs: https://web.archive.org/web/20220305125849/https://www.graphql-code-generator.com/docs/guides/react#apollo-and-urql

Comment: "The preset: "client" is not meant to be used in combination with other plugins. You must use either the client-preset or typescript-urql-plugin which provides 2 different ways to get typed GraphQL Operations." - this was very helpful but the documentation should be very explicit about this. I never saaw this anywhere in the docs.