# Multiple exports with the same name in graphql.ts file after runnig pnpm run codegen

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, codegen

stack using
ractjs (typescript)
Graphql
**Problem facing** I am trying to generate graphql.ts file using codegen, but when I generate I get duplicate exports. here is my codegen config file.

also i ([GraphQL Codegen duplicates RegisterDocument with typescript-urql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74130622/graphql-codegen-duplicates-registerdocument-with-typescript-urql)),(https://github.com/dotansimha/graphql-code-generator/issues/8123) tried the same way but didn't help

codegen setup:

```
import type { CodegenConfig } from '@graphql-codegen/cli'

const config: CodegenConfig = {
    overwrite: true,
    schema: 'http://localhost:1337/graphql',
    documents: './src/**/*.graphql',
    generates: {
        './src/gql/': {
            preset: 'client',
            plugins: [
                'typescript',
                'typescript-operations',
                {
                    'typescript-react-apollo': {
                        // Set the `hooks` option to `true` to generate hooks for queries
                        hooks: true
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}

export default config
```

i need fix this error   Multiple exports with the same

Comment: the comment here https://stackoverflow.com/a/74137167/6429674 specifies that `The preset: "client" is not meant to be used in combination with other plugins. ` (which you are doing)